# How to handle Modals in cucumber + Capybara + Selenium

Tags: ruby, cucumber, modal-dialog, capybara

So I am trying to click a forgot password link (which causes a modal pop up) and confirm the pop up link so I can perform a test on the sent out email.

My code looks like this:

```
   page.find(:css, '#launch-modal-link').click  # code fails on this line, after clicking the link

   page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept  # does not get to this line of code.
```

What am I doing wrong exactly when trying to click the "Ok" button in the modal pop up?

Do I need to add a try catch block (or whatever it is called in Ruby) around the link

Comment: Seems to be related to this article - http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2012/03/23/webdriver-modaldialog/

Comment: "code fails on this line" - can you add in the error message that you see?

Comment: @JonM - The error message I am getting says "There is an unhandled alert"

Comment: To be more precise, I am getting a "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError" error. And the exact message reads "Modal Dialog Present"

Comment: Is it possible that the dialog is appearing earlier than your test expects, i.e. before clicking the link?  I thought that error appeared when trying to perform some action when an alert is already present.

Comment: no, the click action is what is causing the modal to appear. Just to give an example, the 'launch-modal-link' is the form submit button. A modal is appearing after I click this link because a field is invalid or whatever the reason is. So, no, the modal is not appearing before this occurs.

Comment: Which line does the backtrace show the error occurring at?  Your 'page.find...' line or the 'page.driver.browser.switch_to...' line?  Or something else?  Including the full backtrace would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it - Found the answer somewhere else. Its a hack though, and not something done via cucumber directly.

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```

This works because it over writes the confirm() to always return true and the confirm function seems to be a common javascript function to return the button clicked in a dialog box. Could be wrong about that. (read the javascript function being performed onclick. Might not always work)